# IF, better approach

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm have the
 [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjZgv.png) below and I want to count how many times a row value is greater than 2.

[image]

Please note the columns are linked, 1st column->3rd , 2nd->4th .
Sometimes I want to count if tms = "**abc**", and sometimes if they are opposite of **abc**.

Is there any different approach for this case?

```
var_case = 1;
var tms = "abc";   
foreach (DataRow r in d.Rows)
{
        gCount+= cases(r, _case, tms, true) ? 1 : 0;
       // gCount+= cases(r, _case, tms) ? 1 : 0;
}
private bool cases(DataRow d, int _case, string tms = "", bool t = false)
{
        var h = d.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        bool res = false;
        switch (_case)
              {
              case 1: res = (h == tms) ? ((!t) ? ((int)d.ItemArray[2] > 2) ? true : false : ((int)d.ItemArray[3] > 2) ? true : false) : ((!t) ? ((int)d.ItemArray[3] > 2) ? true : false: ((int)d.ItemArray[2] > 2) ? true : false); break;
              default:
                     break;
              }
return res;
}
```

Comment: This question may be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you sure there is exactly one "abc" in every row? Because your code rely on that.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek, yes 100% sure.

Comment: It can be closed, found the solution my self. Thank you all.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to count the rows, making the rows counting more explicit.

```
var _case = 1;
var tms = "abc";
int gCount = table.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Count(r => cases(r, _case, tms, false));
```

In the condition, you can separate the retrieving of the column index and getting the data. It would make things less complicated.

```
private static bool cases(DataRow dataRow, int _case, string tms = "", bool invertedSearch = false)
{
    switch (_case)
    {
        case 1:
            string h = (string)dataRow.ItemArray[0];
            int column = (h == tms) ^ invertedSearch ? 2 : 3;
            return (int)dataRow.ItemArray[column] > 2;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```